# Show message based on cart total before order review table in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

On my WooCommerce checkout page, I am trying to show a notification before the order review section when the total of the cart equals €0.01

So far, I have placed the following in the `functions.php` file of my child theme:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'test_funtion');
function test_funtion(){
    ?>
        <p>Notice goes here</p>
    <?php
}
```

---

How can I modify these lines such that this notice is only shown if the order total equals € 0.01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WC_Cart::get_cart_contents_total();](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartget_cart_contents_total/) - Gets cart total. This is the total of items in the cart, but after discounts. Subtotal is before discounts.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review () {
    // Get cart total
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
    
    // Compare
    if ( $cart_total == 0.01 ) {
        echo '<p>' . __( 'My message', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 10, 0 );
```